# ViewController inside container- why do I read the screen height?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am struggling for hours to make a viewController that is being loaded into a container , to get the container height, not the screen height.

**On storyboard:** I set a container view(inside some VC), linked to a viewController window(by storyboard), which get the class name of my viewController  = `mainVC`.

**On "mainVC" class, on viewDidLoad** : `view.frame.height = 667` (iPhone 8 ) .

But , this container's height is 600, and mainVC is linked into this container.

Also, on simulator, this **mainVC is really presented as 600**. (not full screen)

How would I fix this ?

Comment: When you say `linked to a viewcontroller window(by storyboard)` do you mean linked through storyboard refrence? And have you set `containerview` constraints also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out after reading about it that only on

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
```

you get the real frame.height as expected.

On `viewDidLoad` , the view size is still not being initiated .

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to get parent view frame size:

```
super.view.frame.height
```

or try this:

```
subview.frame = parentView.bounds

subview.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
```

Comment: that is not a solution, its a patch.

Comment: You may use above code in `viewWillAppear` as correctly suggested by @Curnelious or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Both will work.